# Drupal, Displaying a Content list of a User from their Profile, accessible by anyone via Views

Tags: drupal, view

I am running Drupal 7 and I would like to know how to create a View that displays as a tab on a users profile that displays all of his or her created content. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcAf4.png) is what I have so far, but it only shows the tab for the logged in user, no one else can access it.

I got most of the code from [here.](https://drupal.org/node/1108312)

Answer (score 0):

Its a permission issue, You have been created the View Block. So Enable the permission for `Anonymous` User.

Comment: I changed the permission to all the roles, and nothing changed.

Comment: its a block view or page view?

Comment: It is a page view, the configurations are here. 

http://imgur.com/kQcyN5y,zTcawNR#0